# Java Spring schema produces error in xml

Tags: java, spring-mvc, xml-schema-collection

Java Spring schema produces error in web project.
Interesting is that this code has been deployed with no error on one machine and on another this error comes up

[image]

and the result when trying to run:

[image]

I never met before issue with reference to loose.dtd file in dispatcher servlet xml.

dispatcher-servlet.xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.5.xsd
">

<bean    id="HandlerMapping"  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.BeanNameUrlHandlerMapping"/>

<bean name="/" class="com.pizzaorder.controller.PizzaOrder" />


<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver" >
    <property name="prefix">
        <value>/WEB-INF/views/</value>
    </property>
    <property name="suffix">
        <value>.jsp</value>
    </property>
</bean>


</beans>
```

Any idea why it occurs and how to fix?
Thanks

Comment: Can u try changing it from `spring-beans-3.5.xsd "\n"
">`  to `spring-beans-3.5.xsd">` I have tried using "\n" to depict a new line.

Comment: yes, I tried. problem still exists.